# Encoding issue of str() for list or tuple in python2

Tags: python, string, list, encoding, tuples

In my script I get error message from DB and want to show it in a web page. It's working perfect while I don't get local letters in error message.
Message is tuple.

```py
>>> # coding: utf-8
...

# string with u
>>> data1 = (1, u'Это мой текст')
>>> print data1[1]
Это мой текст
>>> print str(data1)
(1, u'\u042d\u0442\u043e \u043c\u043e\u0439 \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442')

# string without u
>>> data2 = (1, 'Это мой текст')
>>> print data2[1]
Это мой текст
>>> print str(data2)
(1, '\xd0\xad\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9   \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd1\x82')

# I want like this
>>> str(data2).???  # WHAT I HAVE TO DO???
(1, 'Это мой текст')

# Current solution for me, but I want to know about better and more beautiful solution
>>> print ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, str) else str(x), data2))
1, Это мой текст
```

Can you help me find (???) method and explain why it's happening.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Please edit your post to add the error you're receiving.

Comment: I'm not receiving error, but output on the web page like this: "(1, '\xd0\xad\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9   \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd1\x82')"

Comment: so what's wrong with your solution ?

Comment: I want to know about better and beautiful solution. Like this: str(data2).???, where ??? one or two standard methods. I was playing with decode() and encode(), but I hadn't gotten what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

When you print an object (turple in your case), you get the output of the `__str__` method of the object. The `__str__` methods of different objects are different: for string it is a string without quotes, for turple it creates a string containing the opening and closing `()` and the string produced by the `__repr__` method of each object contained within. To get the result that you want you should to combine methods (by checking type of objects), for example:

```
print ", ".join(map(lambda x: not isinstance(x, basestring) and str(x) or x, [1, "абв"]))
print ", ".join(map(lambda x: not isinstance(x, basestring) and str(x) or x, [1, u"абв"]))
```

Also, of course, there is a lagre number of tricks. For example, you may use dumping method from `json` library:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(("message", "уеуке"), ensure_ascii=False))
# ["message", "уеуке"]
print(json.dumps(("message", u"уеуке"), ensure_ascii=False))
# ["message", "уеуке"]
```